# Django form clean() method not raising errors when a ValidationError occurs

Tags: django, forms, validation

I am trying to create a custom validator for my form by overwriting the clean() method, and for some reason validation errors are not being raised properly. Here's my code:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    email_field = forms.EmailField(label='E-mail address', max_length=128)

    def clean(self):
         cleaned_data = super(EmailForm, self).clean()
         email = cleaned_data.get('email')

         try:
            u = get_user_model().objects.get(email=email)
            raise forms.ValidationError("E-mail already in database.")
            print('validation error raised')
        except:
            pass
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages

from .forms import EmailForm

def email_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailForm(request.POST)

        # If the form is valid...
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, "Kaboom! Your referral e-mail was sent. Hang tight - we'll be sure to let you know when your friend makes a purchase.")
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Error!')
   else:
       form = EmailForm()

   return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
```

**template.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'form-process' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

When I submit this form with input that should raise a validation error (i.e., an e-mail address that is already associated with a user in my database), I get the 'success' message rather than an error. The strangest part about it is that 'validation error raised' is printed in my console — but for some reason the form processes and form.is_valid() passes as True.

Can anyone tell me why form.is_valid doesn't output an error in the code below when a duplicate e-mail is entered?

Comment: What do you think this clause is doing? `except: Pass`

Comment: That clause should only trigger if the e-mail address is not already associated with a user in the database, right? If I enter an e-mail address that is already in the database, it should stay in the 'try' block and raise a validation error.

Comment: All exceptions raised in a `try` block are caught by any `except` clause that matches the exception, including those explicitly `raise`d. That's kind of the whole point of `try/except`.

Comment: `except: pass` is *always* a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't raise exception, because you catch is in except.

```
def clean(self):
     cleaned_data = super(EmailForm, self).clean()
     email = cleaned_data.get('email')

     users = get_user_model().objects.filter(email=email)
     if users.exists():
         raise forms.ValidationError("E-mail already in database.")
```

Comment: `if users.exists():` is marginally better.